# left join same table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables (Agents) and (Customers)

Agents

```
| id | agent_name | leader_id|
------------------------------
| 1  | AAA        |          |
| 2  | BBB        |     1    |
| 3  | CCC        |     1    |
| 4  | DDD        |          |
| 5  | EEE        |     4    |
```

Customers

```
| id | customer_name |agent_id|
-------------------------------
| 1  |      ABC1     |        |
| 2  |      ABC2     |    1   |
| 3  |      ABC3     |    3   |
| 4  |      ABC4     |    3   |
| 5  |      ABC5     |    5   |
```

I used LEFT JOIN to list all Customers with Agent Name

```
SELECT *, Customers.id AS id, Agents.id AS aid 
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Agents ON Customers.agent_id = Agents.id
```

How I can list Customers of specific team using leader_id ?

Comment: How do you define a *team*? Your tables have no such column.

Comment: leader_id define that this agent belong to his team, the leader also an agent

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: I need all columns including id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve our problem

`SELECT *, Customers.id AS id, Agents.id AS aid FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Agents ON Customers.agent_id = Agents.id where Agents.id = {1} or Agents.leader_id = {1}`

Where, {1}  could be any value

Correct me if this doesn't workout

Comment: This work when providing leader_id and agent.id, How you can modify it so it will show all team customers by providing only the leader_id

Comment: It should work similarly, just replace {1} with any leader_id

Comment: Thank you so so so so so much god bless you